# file_get_contents() with newLine for Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a file called **mail.txt** with the following contents :

```
From: elvis@tabloid.org (The King)
Subject: be seein' ya around
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2006 11:04:13
From: The Prez <president@whitehouse.gov>
Date: Wed, 25 Oct 2006 8:36:24
Subject: now, about your vote
```

I'm using **Sublime Text** in which the Regex `^\w+:` works properly.

I'm using **`file_get_contents()`** to read the content from **mail.txt** and then use the same Regex for **`preg_replace()`** to highlight the output.

The issue is, when I use **`file_get_contents()`**, it doesn't consider `\n` and for that I tried `nl2br()`, but that didn't work either.

Below are the outputs in Sublime and PHP :

- **Sublime**

[image]

---

- **PHP**

[image]

Below is the PHP code :

```
<?php  
    $path = "./mail.txt";
    if(!file_exists($path))
        die("File does not exist");
    else {
        if(!($handle = fopen($path, "r")))
            die("File could not be opened");
        else {
            $file_data = file_get_contents($path);
        }
    }
    $mod_file = preg_replace("/^\w+:/", "<span class='replaced'>$0</span>", $file_data);
    echo "<pre>".$mod_file."</pre>";
?>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `m` or `Multiline` flag.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/12

```
$re = "/^\\w+:/m"; 
$str = "From: elvis@tabloid.org (The King)\nSubject: be seein' ya around\nDate: Mon, 23 Oct 2006 11:04:13\nFrom: The Prez <president@whitehouse.gov>\nDate: Wed, 25 Oct 2006 8:36:24\nSubject: now, about your vote"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: @Sidsec9:the trap is that sublimtext and notepad++ use the multiline mode by default (that is not the case in PHP).

Comment: I'm supposed to wait for 38 seconds